# Can a Node.js server accept incoming requests while the event queue is blocked?

Tags: node.js, blocking

So I'm just starting to dive into Node and I understand that the I/O is non-blocking and that the event loop is blocking but what I am wondering is:

**If you have code which is blocking the event queue, will the server still be able to place incoming requests at the end of the queue or will all of them just time out/bounce?**

Comment: That's a good question someone familiar with the internals of Node.js can answer. I *suspect* that the ``http`` object's C++ library is handling the actual I/O in a separate thread, so it *should* be queueing up requests (perhaps not actually adding events onto the queue until the event loop is given control again and pending events are interpreted and added?)

Comment: From what I've read I know the I/O is asnychronous, but after briefly googling the internals of how asynchronous programming works, I read that async doesn't spawn new threads? Is that true?

Comment: "asynchronous programming promotes using the same thread to process multiple requests, sequentially, but with no request blocking the thread, as we will see later the operations performed by requests will be executed "in pieces.""
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61693

Comment: That's true of all of your code inside of Node.js's Javascript event loop. C++ extensions can completely ignore that, and essentially all I/O in Node.js (TCP and UDP ports, files, stdin/out/err, other processes' stdin/out/err, etc) are implemented in C++ extensions in Node.js, so I've always assumed those are really done in parallel.

Comment: Hmmm okay. So I wonder if incoming requests and I/O callbacks sit in some kind of 'purgatory' for a while until the event loop is free to accept them... or if the incoming requests will just be denied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with node, or at least this discussion so far introduces no evidence of node's behavior.

The TCP stack *itself* accepts connection into a queue of its own without help from the program that is using the accepting socket. If that queue fills, further requests are made to wait until the TCP connection queue has space. Such "unacceptable" connections are not bounced, though they could time out if things get really delayed.

Bottom line, however, is that the sample answer, using curl, does not prove anything beyond the basic behavior of the TCP stack, but that probably doesn't matter, because the original poster's concern was that connections might bounce. That will only happen if your server is so overloaded (or badly written perhaps) that it is effectively overloaded, and dumping some requests is the best chance it has of at least providing some service to some users.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this answer. I was not at all aware of the TCP Stack

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The server is still able to queue up requests. To demonstrate, I made the following file which blocks for 10 seconds, ran it, and curl'd the server on another terminal.

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log('got a request!');
  res.end('hello world!\n');
}).listen(3000);

var t = Date.now();
console.log('blocking..');
while(t + 10000 > Date.now());
console.log('not blocking anymore');
```

The result from running it

```
blocking..
not blocking anymore
got a request!
```

Comment: Alright I think that answers it well. I'm wondering if the incoming requests were placed on the queue after the blocking occurred and then logged 'got a request' or if the incoming request was placed on the queue DURING the blocking and then 'got a request' was fired off after after the event loop was free'd up.

Comment: This does answer the more important aspect of the question though, the incoming requests did not bounce... which was my main concern. Thank you good sir

Comment: If the I/O is truly async it should have been placed during the block, but if the event queue is blocked I don't see how it would be able to accept more events... unless the queue itself sits in the asynchronous environment and each event is handled in the blocking environment... i guess the question is weather the event queue itself is in the async or blocking environment... but for all intensive purposes, the question is answered. I can sleep at night.

Comment: How would you go about making that `while` loop non blocking in node?

Comment: In the event where your code becomes a slow algorithm that noticeably blocks, you can either run it in another process or use `process.nextTick()`.